# strtotime bug with recognizing last month

Tags: php, strtotime

```
echo strtotime("first day of last month");
```

returns `1317492376`but it's 6 pm of 1 september! Shouldn't it return the timestamp of first second of the month? If not, how to get it?

Comment: Do you happen to be in GMT+6?

Comment: What is your timezone offset?

Comment: No, I am not in GMT +6. I am in +3 GMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` doesn't touch the time part when you specify only the date. Try this:

```
strtotime( "first day of last month 00:00" )
```